# iphone application crash for CA :transaction

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios6, core-animation

My application is crashing when i tried to push the view controller with ios 6, it seems to be working fine in ios 5. Crash details are as follows

0x17aebd0 CA::Transaction::ensure crash.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this is because of setting same background view to the two different tableviews, i have fixed this issue by setting different background views to the tableviews

UIView *lView=[[UIView alloc]init];
 [self.mTableView setBackgroundView:lView];
 [lView release];
 lView=nil;

lView=[[UIView alloc]init];
[self.mTableView2 setBackgroundView:lView];
 [lView release];
 lView=nil;